# backgroundworker and different thread

Tags: c#, wpf, int, backgroundworker

I have a `WinForm` application and want to convert to `WPF`, after the 200 errors was clean, I'm trying to get works and always have one errors I'm not able to resolve.

At my `BackgroundWorker1_DoWork` I'm trying to retrieve how many files in a directory by using this:

```
//Set the progress bar
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render,
   new Action(() => { 
      Directory.GetFiles((textBox_UpdatedBuildPath.Text, "*",
          SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length; 
   })
);           //<-----------------HERE
```

and get following error:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

After quick search, it's seemed to be related when user want to update UI, but it seems that it is not my case, I need informations from `Textbox` and recursively find how many files folder can contains.

Thank's for future answer.

Edit: Here the code with full comment -> http://codepaste.net/r1qejd

Comment: Wrong dispatcher, use textBox_UpdatedBuildPath.Dispatcher instead.  Ask a team member of friend to review your code, don't code alone.

Comment: You mean replace `textBox_UpdatedBuildPath.Text` TO `textBox_UpdatedBuildPath.Dispatcher`   ?

Comment: No.  You did it correctly on the RichTextBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost every WPF element has thread affinity. This means that access to such an element should be made only from the thread that created the element. In order to do so, every element that requires thread affinity is derived, eventually, from `DispatcherObject` class. This class provides a property named `Dispatcher` that returns the `Dispatcher` object associated with the WPF element.

The `Dispatcher` class is used to perform work on his attached thread. It has a queue of work items and it is in charge of executing the work items on the dispatcher thread.

[You can find on the following link some more details on the subject.](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/arik/2010/08/12/wpf-inside-out-dispatcher/)

As MSDN says:

> Only one thread can modify the UI thread. But how do background
>   threads interact with the user? A background thread can ask the UI
>   thread to perform an operation on its behalf. It does this by
>   registering a work item with the Dispatcher of the UI thread. The
>   Dispatcher class provides two methods for registering work items:
>   Invoke and BeginInvoke. Both methods schedule a delegate for
>   execution. Invoke is a synchronous call – that is, it doesn’t return
>   until the UI thread actually finishes executing the delegate.
>   BeginInvoke is asynchronous and returns immediately.

So try to use `Dispatcher`. For example:

```
int CountFileToCheck;    
textBox_UpdatedBuildPath.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
    CountFileToCheck=Directory.GetFiles(textBox_UpdatedBuildPath.Text, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length; 
});
```

**Update:**

I've made an axample for you and tested it. It works perfectly.

**XAML:**

```
<StackPanel>
   <Button Name="btn" Click="btn_Click" Content="Foo Button"/>   
   <TextBox Name="textBox" Text="123"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    BackgroundWorker bw;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bw.DoWork += (o, a) =>
        {
            try
            {
                string str = "";
                textBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => 
                { 
                    str = textBox.Text;
                    MessageBox.Show(str);     
                }));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            //e.Result = LoadXmlDoc();
        };            
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

}

Comment: I can't do this like that due to I take back this int value for calculate percent. I update my first post with a link for the complete code, can you check in that way for another way to avoid this error ? :)

Comment: I have updated code, the next line is `int TotalSteps = CountFileToCheck + HowManyFixSteps;//Count total steps` and I got error _Use of unassigned local variable 'CountFileToCheck'_  :(

Comment: @Cory  try to set `int CountFileToCheck=0;`

Comment: I have try it, get no error but the int keep value to 0 (null) and don't be updated by the `Dispatcher.invoke`

Comment: @Cory try to set `textBox_UpdatedBuildPath.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
    CountFileToCheck=5; 
});` and say please what happens

Comment: Same error, be sure we are on the same road, I have put the updated code here: [link](http://codepaste.net/i9nvab)

Comment: @Cory I've made an example for you. Please, see my update answer. Feel free to ask any question.

Comment: The answer you given is correct and probably I don't have write my question correctly because I have a lot of error when I take my worker code from WinForm to WPF ..  So, In the case your answer is correctly reply to the error, I will check as answer and open a new thread (post) and better write my question.

Comment: @Cory yeah. You are right. It is better to ask new question in new thread. It gives clearance and simplicity.